# How to capture/sniff network traffic of certain process (executable) in Python?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, packet, packet-sniffers

I am trying to listen and capture network traffic (packets) of certain process (.exe executable on Windows) using Python.

So far using `scapy` I am able to sniff the network...

Here for example I am sniffing all UDP packet in between port 10 to 20 and print out the remote IP address and port.

```py
from scapy.all import *

def capture_traffic(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(IP) and packet.haslayer(UDP):
        print(f"Remote Address: {packet[IP].src} | Remote Port: {packet[UDP].sport}")

sniff(filter="udp and portrange 10-20", prn=capture_traffic)
```

I also know that using `psutil` I can get process PID like so:

```py
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if "some_app.exe" in process.name():
        process_pid = process.pid
        break
```

**How can I sniff/capture traffic/packet from only the one specific process?**

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `pcap` and `psutils` module, the first to sniff the packets and the second just to get the `PID`

Here is how you could do it:

```
import pcap
import psutil
import os

process_name = "some_app.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    if proc.info['name'] == process_name:
        pid = proc.info['pid']
        break

pcap_session = pcap.pcap(name=os.getenv('PCAP_INTERFACE', 'eth0'), promisc=True, immediate=True)

for ts, pkt in pcap_session:
    if pcap_session.datalink() == pcap.DLT_LINUX_SLL:
        pkt = pkt[2:]
    elif pcap_session.datalink() == pcap.DLT_EN10MB:
        pkt = pkt[14:]
    try:
        if psutil.Process(pid).connections(kind='inet', _fd=pkt):
            print(f"Captured packet: {pkt}")
    except (psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.NoSuchProcess):
        continue
```

Once we have opened a live capture session on the network we loop over all packets captured by `pcap` and just check if the destination IP matches the target process with `psutils` then if we foud we just print it

Comment: What are the differences between `pcap` and `scapy`?

Comment: pcap is a low-level library for capturing and analyzing network traffic, while Scapy is a high-level Python library for interactive packet manipulation and network analysis.

Comment: Is it possible to filter by protocol and port using `pcap`?

Comment: Yes you have a wide range of options available, I suggest you look at the documentation

Comment: I have issues installing `pcap` (AttributeError: module 'distutils.sysconfig' has no attribute '_init_posix'_). I probably would therefore have preference with `scapy` over `pcap`.